# ¿Cómo redireccionar cuando alguien termine un formulario en mi pagina web?

Tags: php

He descargado una plantilla que venia ya con un codigo PHP por defecto. Todo correcto, únicamente que al enviar el formulario, no pasa nada, llega la información al correo de gmail, pero la pagina no se actualiza o redirecciona al index, quisiera que me ayudara. dejo el php:

```
<?php

    $to = "micorreo@gmail.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
    $cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $subject = "Has recibido un nuevo mensaje desde mi pagina web";

    $logo = 'img/logo/hvs_logo.png';
    $link = 'index.html';

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Express Mail</title></head><body>";
    $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
    $body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
    $body .= "<a href='{$link}'><img src='{$logo}' alt=''></a><br><br>";
    $body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
    $body .= "</tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    
    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Empleando el método **[header](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)** puedes redirigir a la página que quieras una vez hayas enviado el email.

Añade estas líneas al final de tu código

```
header("Location: /gracias.html");
exit;
```

Reemplazando `gracias.html` por la página que quieras mostrar.

Más información sobre este método pinchando [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php).

Answer (score 0):

Hola al finalizar tu send();
Puedes colocar la siguiente linea de codigo `header("Location: /index.html");`